# Error after npm run eject

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm, reactjs-native

I am learning how to make a mobile app using react native but every time I run in the terminal npm run eject it gives me this error at the end I tried several npm versions but I keep always getting this error

```
Ejected successfully!
Please consider letting us know why you ejected in this survey:
  goo.gl/forms/iD6pl218r7fn9N0d2
The batch file cannot be found.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! hello-world2@0.1.0 eject: `react-native-scripts eject`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the hello-world2@0.1.0 eject script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-06-05T11_28_47_708Z-debug.log
```

Comment: please supply your OS, npm and Node versions

Comment: And also the relevant parts from `2018-06-05T11_28_47_708Z-debug.log`